# Geth 1.6 - how to get data from console

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity

I am trying to compile a simple contract in a private blockchain

**simpleContract.sol**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract SimpleStorage {   
  uint storedData;

  function set(uint x) {
    storedData = x;   
  }

  function get() constant returns (uint) {
    return storedData;   
  } 
}
```

I get compiled version using

```
$echo "var simpleOutput=`solc --optimize --combined-json abi,bin,interface simpleContract.sol`" > simpleStorage.js
```

Starting a private geth console with an open account, I run

```
>loadScript("simpleStorage.js")
```

After verifying simpleOutput, I run

```
>var simpleStorageContract = web3.eth.contract([{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"x","type":"uint256"}],"name":"set","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"get","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"}]);
```

followed by

```
>var simpleStorage = simpleStorageContract.new(   {     from: web3.eth.accounts[0],      data: "0x" + simpleOutput.contracts["simpleContract.sol:SimpleStorage"].bin,      gas: '47000'   }, function (e, contract){    console.log(e, contract);    if (typeof contract.address !== 'undefined') {         console.log('Contract mined! address: ' + contract.address + ' transactionHash: ' + contract.transactionHash);    } })
```

I ran the miner with

```
>miner.start()
```

When I check simpleStorage, I get

```
> simpleStorage
{
  abi: [{
      constant: false,
      inputs: [{...}],
      name: "set",
      outputs: [],
      payable: false,
      type: "function"
  }, {
      constant: true,
      inputs: [],
      name: "get",
      outputs: [{...}],
      payable: false,
      type: "function"
  }],
  address: undefined,
  transactionHash: "0xabce95ae8e0b4f5422b58acd02ab28e18aa0b6cf0a7e94da07e11128e53ae719"
}
```

However, when I try

```
>simpleStorage.get()
```

I get

> TypeError: 'get' is not a function
>       at :1:1

How do I know that the miner has mined the contract?

What is the way around this?

Comment: Just off top of my head, did you try `simpleStorage.get.call()`?

Comment: I tried and got
TypeError: Cannot access member 'call' of undefined
    at <anonymous>:1:1

Comment: Unfortunately, i'm not sitting in front of my geth console, so cant double check your results. Hopeful someone else will be able to help. Are you sure that tx got mined though?

Comment: I ran the miner.start() and waiting for a couple of minutes when it printed that it mined potential block. Not sure. Any suggestions on how to verify that it was mined?

Comment: You can use [getTransaction](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgettransaction) to check in which block is your txs.

Comment: I have spent an hour and did not get it. Maybe I am making an error. Can you verify?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61339/discussion-between-trialcritic-and-newtwoeth).

Comment: I notice one issue. The simpleStorage has the abi, address and transactionHash, but does not have get and set functions. This is a problem. Any suggestions for this?